# Сreating polygon from coordinates in GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinates, geopandas, polygon-creation

How to create a polygon from coordinates in GeoPandas with Python?

Comment: If this is a working code, it seems more suited for Code Review stack ( https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but the GIS libraries are quite specific, so I'm not sure whether it could stay here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This simple code is working for Python 3.9 and geopandas 0.9.0, and it works for older versions too.

### Separate lists with latitude and longitude coordinates

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

lat_point_list = [50.854457, 52.518172, 50.072651, 48.853033, 50.854457]
lon_point_list = [4.377184, 13.407759, 14.435935, 2.349553, 4.377184]

polygon_geom = Polygon(zip(lon_point_list, lat_point_list))
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[polygon_geom])       

polygon.to_file(filename='polygon.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
polygon.to_file(filename='polygon.gpkg', driver="GPKG")
polygon.to_file(filename='polygon.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

### One list with longitude and latitude coordinates

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

lon_lat_list = [[4.373352367, 52.091372156], [4.373360755, 52.091365819], [4.373384852, 52.091347618], [4.373410766, 52.091360632], [4.37337828, 52.09138517], [4.373352367, 52.091372156]]

polygon_geom = Polygon(lon_lat_list)
polygon = gpd.GeoDataFrame(index=[0], crs='epsg:4326', geometry=[polygon_geom])       

polygon.to_file(filename='polygon.geojson', driver='GeoJSON')
polygon.to_file(filename='polygon.gpkg', driver="GPKG")
polygon.to_file(filename='polygon.shp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

### (Bonus) Visualize polygon with folium 0.12.1

```
import folium
m = folium.Map([50.854457, 4.377184], zoom_start=5, tiles='cartodbpositron')
folium.GeoJson(polygon).add_to(m)
folium.LatLngPopup().add_to(m)
m
# if using Spyder.5
import webbrowser
m.save('test.html')
webbrowser.open_new_tab('test.html')
```

[image]

Comment: Updated the page to make question and answer more readable. In this answer improvements were added by ImanolUr, gene and reevesii to the code!

Answer (score 5):

I would substitute the for loop for:

```
polygon_geom = zip(lon_list, lat_list)
```

Comment: With `zip()` simply use  `polygon_geom = zip(lon_point_list,lat_point_list)` (there is no need for list comprehension here)

Comment: Indeed, I'll edit the answer.

Comment: The format of shapely geometries  is `(x,y)`, so `(longitude, latitude)` and not `(latitude, longitude)`

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Stupid mistake to reverse longitude and latitude, but the syntax of shapely felt very similar to WKT strings. Next time I should check on the map.

Answer (score 4):

This solution works for large data via `.dissolve` and `.convex_hull`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x": [0, 1, 0.1, 0.5, 0, 0, -1, 0],
        "y": [0, 0, 0.1, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, -1],
        "label": ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
    }
)
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    df,
    geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df["x"], df["y"]),
)
# Outputs
"""
gdf
     x    y  label                  geometry
0  0.0  0.0      a   POINT (0.00000 0.00000)
1  1.0  1.0      a   POINT (1.00000 1.00000)
2  0.1  0.1      a   POINT (0.10000 0.10000)
3  0.5  0.5      a   POINT (0.50000 0.50000)
4  0.0  1.0      a   POINT (0.00000 1.00000)
5  0.0  0.0      b   POINT (0.00000 0.00000)
6 -1.0  0.0      b  POINT (-1.00000 0.00000)
7  0.0 -1.0      b  POINT (0.00000 -1.00000)
"""

res = gdf.dissolve("label").convex_hull
res.to_wkt()

# Outputs
"""
label
a       POLYGON ((0 0, 0 1, 1 0, 0 0))
b    POLYGON ((0 -1, -1 0, 0 0, 0 -1))
dtype: object
"""
```

[image: polygon created with geopandas]